# Kotlin coroutines Inappropriate blocking method call (tcp sockets)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm getting this warning when working with sockets. I'm calling the startConnection method from IO scope coroutine and if the startConnection method is suspend I get the warning. I make it a suspend, because later I'm calling some other suspend methods from it. Is there any way around this or should I suppress the warning?

```
private suspend fun startConnection(ip: String, port: Int) {
    try {
        socket = Socket(ip, port)
        .
        .
```

Comment: Coroutine should never call blocking function. Regardless of how you are calling this function you should always ensure blocking code is launched in IO dispatchers. Use `socket = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { Socket(ip, port) }`

Comment: I tried your solution, but it still throws the same warning: Inappropriate blocking method call

Comment: As long as the function is "suspend" the warning remains.

Comment: I don't see any such warning for this code: `private suspend fun startConnection(ip: String, port: Int) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { val socket = Socket(ip, port) }`

Comment: Interesting, the exact same code shows me the warning: [image](https://imgur.com/a/OqTlC2m)

Comment: It's not the exact same code, you use `IO` as the dispatcher. If this is anything else but an imported shortcut for `Dispatchers.IO`, for example if it's a `val IO = Dispatchers.IO`, the check fails.

Answer (score 0):

Socket() is a IO call. it's making a actual TCP connection.
In fact, all the calls in the "old IO" framework are blocking calls. You need to allocate a thread for each call (or be ok w/ things locking up for a bit)

coroutines != threads

If you use Dispatch.IO then coroutines == threads (sorta of, but hidden from you), but the compiler doesn't know that's the dispatcher your using so you'll continue to get the same error. If your 100% sure your coroutine is on it's own thread than just ignore it.

Some unsolicited advice : If your using coroutines like threads, maybe it'd be better to just use threads? Using coroutines just seems to be making your life harder (this error for example). If your using Dispatch.IO your going to have to synchronize stuff anyway, just like a thread. Not sure what coroutines is buying you here.

coroutines are just a compiler trick to split your code up and make callbacks out of suspend calls w/o you knowing it. I think of them as cooperative-threading from Windows 3.1 from 1994 (what's old is new again).

You want to get into the sprit of coroutines use the NIO calls. The Async versions are easier to use (you don't have to write you own select() loop). Or use Netty, which is all callbacks all the time, and wrap you coroutines around that (there must be a lib that does that by now...)